# Como dar Break neste código caso retorno sejam dois números iguais

Tags: python, break

boa tarde!

Estou com um problema em que caso o usuário digite, duas cidades iguais, o loop seja interrompido. Porém, mesmo colocando uma condicional e adicionando o BREAK, o loop não para, vocês podem me ajudar?

```
import numpy as np

print("Cidade disponíveis:1,2,3,4,5,6,7")

tp = np.array([[],[0,0,2,11,6,15,11,1],[0,2,0,7,12,4,2,15],[0,11,7,0,11,8,3,13],[0,6,12,11,0,10,2,1], 
[0,15,4,8,10,0,5,13],[0,11,2,3,2,5,0,14],[0,1,15,13,1,13,14,0]])  

for x in range(0,6):
    for y in range(0,6):

        def soma2(x,y):
            resultado3 = tp[x][y]
            return resultado3

        while True:
            
            tp1 = int(input("Digite a cidade origem: "))
            while (tp1 > 7):
                tip1 = int(input("Tente novamente: "))

            tp4 = int(input("Digite a cidade destino obrigatorio: "))
            while (tp4 > 7):
                tp4 = int(input("Tente novamente: "))
                if (tp1 == tp4):
                    break


            destinofinal = soma2(tp1,tp4)
            print(f"A distancia da origem para o destino é: {destinofinal} \n")
```

Comment: se  vc quer para o programa, o jeito mais simples é tem uma função main, e usar um return ao invés de break

Comment: Vc tem um loop dentro de outro, dentro de outro, dentro de outro. Qual deles vc quer parar? Dica: o break sempre interrompe o loop mais interno ao qual ele pertence. Se quer parar outro, tem que mudar a lógica...

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

print("Cidade disponíveis:1,2,3,4,5,6,7")

tp = np.array([[],[0,0,2,11,6,15,11,1],[0,2,0,7,12,4,2,15],[0,11,7,0,11,8,3,13],[0,6,12,11,0,10,2,1], 
[0,15,4,8,10,0,5,13],[0,11,2,3,2,5,0,14],[0,1,15,13,1,13,14,0]])  

for x in range(0,6):
    for y in range(0,6):

        def soma2(x,y):
            resultado3 = tp[x][y]
            return resultado3

        while True:
            
            tp1 = int(input("Digite a cidade origem: "))
            while (tp1 > 7):
                tip1 = int(input("Tente novamente: "))

            tp4 = int(input("Digite a cidade destino obrigatorio: "))
            while (tp4 > 7):
                tp4 = int(input("Tente novamente: "))
            if (tp1 == tp4):
                break


            destinofinal = soma2(tp1,tp4)
            print(f"A distancia da origem para o destino é: {destinofinal} \n")
```

Oi! Drohmar!
Parece que a estrutura if está dentro de outra estrutura de repetição (line 15), quando você da break, ela não sai do "While True" e acaba executando a soma.
Queria testar aqui mas não está pegando a biblioteca numpy.
Espero que funcione!

nandapand4